# Flutter: Unable to load asset "assets/images/image_1.jpg" Exception: Asset not found

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and learning by video's on youtube.
And following the video I did small projects, added images, texts and etc.
While I add images it appeared at first time. But now suddenly I get the following warning on emulator:
***Unable to load asset "assets/images/image_1.jpg" Exception: Asset not found***

I did the pubspec.yaml file settings.

Please help to resolve this problem.

Here is my code

```
class MyFoodPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('Clicked 1');
                },
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/corba_1.jpg')),
          )),
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('Clicked 2');
                  },
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/yemek_1.jpg')),
            ),
          )),
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print('Clicked 3');
                },
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/tatli_1.jpg')),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and pubspec.yaml settings

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

Comment: check proper space while in pubspec.yaml file while declaring assets file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is a little miss on your asset declaration, I fixed it, please try.** this part :   **- assets/images/**

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

so I fixed the directory access above for your asset so you do not need to declare them one by one the asset. <--

Answer (score 1):

in flutter when use any audio or images or any external file you must be to add into pubspec.yamel in assets section like this  :

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/audio/
    - assets/lottieFile/
    - assets/fonts/
```